# Bin packing problem diagram // Latex

Tags: graphics, diagrams, graphs, tikz-pic, examples

I need a diagram/graph like this on a latex document.

I don't know neither the library to make this nor a source/example code.

Any info will help me!

Thaks.

[image]

Comment: This is fairly easy to draw by hand via tikz. But note that this site is **not** a `please do this for me` service. So have a look at tikz and how to draw using it, and then post a more specific question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is with tikz package (type `texdoc tikz` in your terminal for the manual), as daleif suggests. I think the following code is quite self-explanatory and easy to adjust (say, if a rectangle needs an additional 2mm). The last items drawn are inside `\foreach` loops to avoid repeating code, but I hope it's clear enogh.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Colors
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{67FF66}
\definecolor{mycyan} {HTML}{BDE1E4}
\definecolor{mypink} {HTML}{FF66FF}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
  % Axis
  \draw[thick,-latex] (0,0) -- (6,0);
  % Dashed line
  \draw[dashed] (5,0) -- (5,1.5);
  % Red dots
  \draw[fill=red] (0,0) circle (1 mm) node [yshift=-3 mm] {$0$};
  \draw[fill=red] (5,0) circle (1 mm) node [yshift=-3 mm] {$t$};
  % Rectangles
  \draw[fill=mypink]  (0,0.5) rectangle (4  ,1);
  \draw[fill=mygreen] (0,1)   rectangle (3.2,1.5);
  \draw[fill=yellow]  (0,1.5) rectangle (5  ,2);
  \draw[fill=mycyan]  (0,2)   rectangle (4.2,2.5);
  % Division lines
  \foreach\x/\y in {1/0.5, 2/0.5, 3/0.5, 1.7/1, 1.3/1.5, 2.7/1.5, 1/2}
  {%
    \draw (\x,\y) --++ (0,0.5); % <-- relative coordinate, 0.5 cm above (\x,\y) point
  }
  % Labels
  \foreach\i in {1,...,4}
  {%
    \node at (-0.5,2.75-0.5*\i) {$M_\i$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]